# Abrir WhatsApp desde webview android studio

Tags: android-studio, webview-android, whatsapp

Hola a todos y muchas gracias por su tiempo. Antes de escribir mi pregunta me aparecieron posibles soluciones, investigué y no encontré solución.

Tengo un WebView en Android Studio en el cual deseo a través de la api de WhatsApp (https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=54000...) abrir, valga la redundancia, WhatsApp ... pero no puedo, no logro ningún resultado exitoso.

Cabe destacar que por ejemplo sí me funciona usar la api anteriormente mencionada en un navegador común como Chrome. La pregunta/s es/son: tengo que realizar modificaciones en el código del WebView? Necesito permisos especiales? 
Qué se me está escapando?

Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme estaría muy agradecido. Otra vez gracias por su tiempo en leer mi problema.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="UnClick"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Autos" />
    <activity android:name=".Motos" />
    <activity android:name=".Empleos" />
    <activity android:name=".ParaComer" />
    <activity android:name=".Hogar" />
    <activity android:name=".SaludYBelleza" />
    <activity android:name=".Telefonos" />
    <activity android:name=".CampoyMascotas" />
    <activity android:name=".Alquileres" />
    <activity android:name=".Corralon" />
</application>
```

Ese es el Manifest

```
package appsmate.com.unclick;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private String url_Ini = "http://unclickcapilla.esy.es/";
    private String url_Almacen = "http://unclickcapilla.esy.es/almacen.html";
    private String url_Carniceria = "http://unclickcapilla.esy.es/carniceria.html";
    private String url_Verduleria = "http://unclickcapilla.esy.es/verduleria.html";
    private String url_Indumentaria = "http://unclickcapilla.esy.es/indumentaria.html";
    private String url_Resto = "http://unclickcapilla.esy.es/restoranparrillas.html";
    private String url_Delivery = "http://unclickcapilla.esy.es/delivery.html";




    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private WebView webviewsi;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        webviewsi = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewsi);
        WebSettings websetting = webviewsi.getSettings();
        websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        websetting.setSupportZoom(true);
        websetting.setDisplayZoomControls(false);


        webviewsi.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                if (webviewsi.canGoBack()) {
                    webviewsi.goBack();

                }

                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Necesitamos estar conectados a una red para mostrarte el contenido ... :(");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "De nuevo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

            }
        });





        webviewsi.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


            @Override


            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Un momento...");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Solicitando contenido a la base de datos ...");
                mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
                mProgressDialog.show();
                MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                mProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        webviewsi.loadUrl(url_Ini);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }




    @Override

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {



        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.portada) {
            webviewsi.getSettings();
            webviewsi.loadUrl(url_Ini);

        }



        if (id == R.id.almacen) {
            webviewsi.getSettings();
            webviewsi.loadUrl(url_Almacen);

        }
        if (id == R.id.caniceria) {
            webviewsi.getSettings();
            webviewsi.loadUrl(url_Carniceria);
        }
        if (id == R.id.verduleria) {
            webviewsi.getSettings();
            webviewsi.loadUrl(url_Verduleria);
        }
        if (id == R.id.indumentaria) {
            webviewsi.getSettings();
            webviewsi.loadUrl(url_Indumentaria);
        }
        if (id == R.id.resto) {
            webviewsi.getSettings();
            webviewsi.loadUrl(url_Resto);
        }
        if (id == R.id.delivery) {
            webviewsi.getSettings();
            webviewsi.loadUrl(url_Delivery);
        }





        if (id == R.id.autos) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (this, Autos.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        } else if (id == R.id.motos) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, Motos.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_empleos) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, Empleos.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.comidas)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, ParaComer.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }



        else if (id == R.id.hogar) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, Hogar.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        } else if (id == R.id.saludybelleza) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, SaludYBelleza.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if (id == R.id.telefonia) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, Telefonos.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        else if (id == R.id.campoymascotas) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, CampoyMascotas.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        else if (id == R.id.alquileres) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, Alquileres.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        else if (id == R.id.corralon) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, Corralon.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webviewsi.canGoBack()) {
            webviewsi.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }



}
```

Y este es el MainActivity

Comment: Hay algo que me parece valioso destacar. Cuando uso la api https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=54000... en Chrome toco el boton y me habre la aplicación WhatsApp ... esta api es cargada en un sitio web a través de código HTML, que justamente es el que intento mostrar en mi WebView.

Comment: Agrega el código que has tratado para darte una opción, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: muestra el código que utilizas actualmente

Comment: Chicos gracias por sus consejos leí el "cómo preguntar". Y también estoy buscando la forma de mostrar mi código. Son Uds muy amables.

Comment: Al contrario @EmanuelBiancotti gracias por tomarte el tiempo para leer y realizar una buena pregunta para la comunidad, agrega lo que has tratado y al menos de mi parte tengo una opción que darte pero necesitaría ver que realizas, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys Gracias por tu ayuda. Edité mi pregunta agregando el Manifest y el Main Activity. Ojala sirva esta midificación en mi pregunta.

Comment: @EmanuelBiancotti que es lo que te muestra cuando no puedes abrir Whatsapp? no te abre ni la aplicación?

Comment: Bueno lo hace es: mostrar el toast que informa que no hay conexión a internet. Me llama mucho la atención, porque esto no pasa en lo absoluto con otro navegador que no sea WebView. En faq.whatsapp muestran el mismo método que estoy intentand usar. Y que de hecho funciona fuera de la aplicacion webview realizada en con AS.

Comment: @EmanuelBiancotti revisa mi respuesta, primeramente asegura tienes el permiso de internet definido dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml y no creo necesites el WebViewClient().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción la cual no requiere permisos es usar la api para abrir `Whatsapp` desde una página web que es cargada dentro de un `WebView`.

Para esto necesitas definir un [WebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient) que provocará abrir la aplicación, en la página que cargarías en el `WebView` debes tener definido el esquema de `Whatsapp` definiendo el numero telefónico con el "area code", "código de área" o como se llame en tu país, por ejemplo :

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5212345678910&text=Hola,%20soyI%20Emanuel%20Biancotti" class="whatsapplink hideweb" style="background-color:#2DC100">Enviar mensaje.</a>
```

Este sería el código:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);      

    //Página web conteniendo el código para abrir Whatsapp.
    String url = "http://mydomain/webpage.html";        

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //Define WebChromeClient() para el WebView.
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            getWindow().setTitle("Open Whatsapp by Jorgesys");
        }
    });
```

Este es un ejemplo de lo que comento, el área de color azul contiene un `WebView` que carga una página que contiene el enlace para abrir el contacto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente tu aplicación debe tener el permiso para acceder a internet, necesario para cargar la página web dentro del `WebView`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Sos un tremendo crack! No sabés cuanto te agradezco !!! FUNCIONA!!! Gracias x 1000!!! Voy a compartir tu solución con otro muchacho que preguntaba lo mismo. Gracias gracias gracias!

Comment: @EmanuelBiancotti un placer ayudarte no olvides leer [ask] y realizar el [tour] del sitio!